# Code is not visible in tutorial "Writing a Subscriber for gpsd_client (C++)"

Tags: ros, c++, gpsd-client

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

I was going through a tutorial on using the gpsd_client package but then stumbled upon a problem regarding the code. Unfortunately I can't see the code included in the tutorial, due to the error included in the screenshot. Could you please help me with what I am supposed to do? [image: image description]
The tutorial link is given below:
http://wiki.ros.org/gpsd_client/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Subscriber%20for%20gpsd_client%20%28C%2B%2B%29

Best regards,
Feyzi

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392228/code-is-not-visible-in-tutorial-%22writing-a-subscriber-for-gpsd_client-(c++)%22/) by [fyzegekmc](https://answers.ros.org/users/86880/fyzegekmc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-12-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure why the links in the wiki are not longer working, I found the tutorials under this link for now:

http://library.isr.ist.utl.pt/docs/roswiki/gpsd_client(2f)Tutorials(2f)Writing(20)a(20)Subscriber(20)for(20)gpsd_client(2028)C(2b2b29).html

I also created an issue as well in the repo, hopefully it gets corrected soon:
https://github.com/swri-robotics/gps_umd/issues/52

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0